# Map a shell command to execute it into vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want to map, in my `~/vimrc` file, the key `<F4>` in `vim` in order to execute the `indent` program on the file which I'm currently editing. How can I do it?
If I do this,the compatibility with `vi` will be broken?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not even implied by `--help` or the man pages, as it turns out `indent` will process things in a pipeline, reading from standard input (aka, FD 0) and writing to standard output (aka, FD 1) which is what you need to get this to work *within* vim.

Start with the command mapped:

```
map <F4> :!indent<CR>
```

Go to the first line of the file and enter visual mode (<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>).  Then press <kbd>Ctrl-End</kbd>, which will take you to the last line of the file.  It will appear that a block the width of the last line plus one (the newline, which is at the end of all lines in vim), including every line, is highlighted.  It doesn't really matter how wide it is, because if we feed this block through an an external command, the vertical is the only determining factor: if a line is included, it will be the whole line.

So now you press <kbd>F4</kbd> and presto.  **This was tested by me *and it works*.**  IMO, that's simple enough -- plus it means you could indent just a section easily too, instead of the whole file, if you want. Another idea would be to remove the return `<CR>` from the mapping so you have to hit enter yourself, but are also left with the option of adding options to `indent`.  Then you can mix and match different styles, lol.

If you really want to map it to select the whole file automatically, call `indent`, then return to command mode and/or your original position -- I'm sure this is possible using a more elaborate construct.  Unfortunately I don't now anything about programming vim, so I can't tell you how it would go.  But someone may come along that does.  Until then, you'll have to settle for 6 keystrokes (`:1`+return to go to the start  of the file, `ctrl-v` for visual, `ctrl-end` to go to end of file, and finally, `F4`).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
map <F4> !indent %<CR>
```

I think it depend on your system what exactly will happen next, but at least you have to reload the file.

But, what is `indent` actually doing? It sounds like what you try can be achieved in a much easier way.

Comment: It doesn't work.[indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) format a C/C++/Java file in various coding styles like GNU style, K&R style, etc.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Does it alter the original file in place?

Comment: I append your line to my `~/.vimrc`. And when I edit a *.c file and press F4 nothing occurs. However if a introduce the command at vim's status line `:! indent file.c` it changes and ask me to reload the file.